# MySQL extracting values from two columns in one table referring to the same column in a different table and combine NULL and NOT NULL values in result

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I have to columns in a table, place_of_birth and place_of_death (this table contains basic info about actors and artists through time), with integers as values that both refer to the same column in a different table (this table contains the values location_id and location).

How can I run a query that gives me back the place_of_birth and place_of_death values as the respective venue_names for place of birth and place of death?

I've changed my query to the suggested code from the reply I got below. So, now I get the first part of my query right, but the challenge is that the query now only results in returning rows that contains NOT NULL values. How would I go about getting the combined NULL and NOT NULL values? I have searched to find the answer to my question, but so far I can't seem to find exactly what I am looking for.

The names in the tables are fictional and there just as an illustration of the table. The sames goes for the location table

First table - persons:

| person_id | first_name | last_name | place_of_birth | place_of_death |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Doe | 1234 | 1234 |
| 2 | Jane | Doe | 1250 | 2345 |
| 3 | Peter | Smith | 2345 | 1234 |
| 3 | Louis | Smith | Null | Null |
| 3 | Frank | Peterson | Null | Null |

Second table - locations:

| location_id | location |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | Hospital |
| 1250 | At home |
| 2345 | The garden |

This is what my current query looks like:

```
SELECT 
    first_name, last_name, place_of_birth, place_of_death
FROM 
    persons
JOIN
    locations 
    ON persons.place_of_birth = locations.location_id
    AND persons.place_of_death = locations.location_id;
```

This is the output that I want:

| first_name | last_name | place_of_birth | place_of_death |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Doe | Hospital | Hospital |
| Jane | Doe | At home | The garden |
| Peter | Smith | The garden | Hospital |
| Louis | Smith | Null | Null |
| Frank | Peterson | Null | Null |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the desired output, you need to join the `persons` table with the `locations` table twice: once for the `place_of_birth` and once for the `place_of_death`. Here's the corrected query:

```sql
SELECT 
    p.first_name,
    p.last_name,
    birth_location.location AS place_of_birth,
    death_location.location AS place_of_death
FROM 
    persons p
JOIN
    locations birth_location
    ON p.place_of_birth = birth_location.location_id
JOIN
    locations death_location
    ON p.place_of_death = death_location.location_id;
```

This query performs two separate joins with the `locations` table: one for the `place_of_birth` and another for the `place_of_death`. This allows you to retrieve the corresponding location names for both birth and death places. The query uses table aliases (`p`, `birth_location`, and `death_location`) to make the code more readable and to distinguish between the different instances of the `locations` table.